# Send elements to next window under condition after triggering

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So far been dealing with a scenario in Apache Beam where given a certain HTTP code, I may be preserving the elements to restart in the next iteration.

Been implementing this with inner code, only using a time trigger.

```
        .apply(
            "Sample Window",
            Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                .triggering(AfterProcessingTime
                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                .discardingFiredPanes()
        )
```

I was hardcoding my logic to handle the request of, let's say, 200 events. And also storing in-memory those events in case the request failed.

However, checking the docs I saw combined triggering...

```
  Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(
     AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(100),
     AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
```

So did the same in my case.

```
        .apply(
            "Sample Window",
            Window.<KV<String, String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                .triggering(
                    AfterFirst.of(
                        AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(200),
                        AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1))
                    )
                )
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                .discardingFiredPanes()
        )
```

So been wondering now...

If triggered by number of elements within the 1 minute timeframe, what happens with those events? Are they reprocessed again? Should I manually remove them from the Window?

I'm also talking in the case the 200 elements fail. How can I make them prevail in the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger you are setting .discardingFiredPanes()

[This will "discards elements in a pane after they are triggered."](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.html#discardingFiredPanes--)

Any subsequent panes will not contain elements that have already been output.